# fitsSystemWindows pushes action bar down - Nativescript & Android 9.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, nativescript, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

With Nativescript : Setting `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` adds height tot the actionbar on android 9.0. Not setting is stops SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE from working.

[Example picture of the extra height added by Nativescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elix0.jpg)

- Tried setting ADJUST_PAN
- Tried setting ADJUST_RESIZE in main.ts

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "nl.desoftwareontwikkelaar.xxx",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "description": "",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.3",
    "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext": "6.0.0-alpha.2",
    "nativescript-advanced-webview": "3.0.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "8.0.2",
    "nativescript-appversion": "1.4.2",
    "nativescript-calendar": "2.1.0",
    "nativescript-directions": "1.3.0",
    "nativescript-email": "1.5.4",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-mapbox": "4.4.1",
    "nativescript-oauth2": "1.4.3",
    "nativescript-phone": "1.4.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "7.0.0",
    "nativescript-web-image-cache": "5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.0.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.1.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.3",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "0.6.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.18.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "gitHead": "803cec054c44c99eaa59cdc267993e6346f6cb3a",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "De Software Ontwikkelaar"
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
    <style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme for action-bar -->
    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="10005" android:versionName="1.0.5">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What it looks like without the setting and is the expected result. ADJUST_RESIZE doesnt work here because the value of fitsSystemWindows isn't set to true.

[Example expected result and current result without the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugt6e.jpg)

Comment: Try calling `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` on your nativeView of your root layout instead of applying it on Activity.

Comment: Tried setting it in the app.component.ts (constructor and OnInit, this is the root after main.ts, which bootstraps the app), no luck.'''if (isAndroid) {
            this._page.android.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        }'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a major problem for my development team in Android. We have tried everything we can think of to fix this and still no joy. We have spent days being frustrated by this simple problem.

NativeScript team - Please, please can you have another look at this problem.

Basically setting android:fitsSystemWindows in styles.xml along with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the Android Manifest causes the Status bar / Action Bar to change height when the keyboard is displayed.

You need to do this otherwise the keyboard overlays the content underneath and there is no way to get to form fields etc.

I am fairly certain this is not related to RadSideDraw. We removed the sidedraw and the problem still persists.

We have found a work around to stop this problem at runtime...
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/730#issuecomment-546592655

However during development every time you save your work and the emulator / phone reloads the Actionbar is then pushed under the statusbar. When the keyboard is displayed the Actionbar then correctly re positions itself.

Comment: Thank you for that solution, at least i can make a working copy now! I